# Automatic Traffic Light in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to design an Automated Traffic Light in Tkinter but I seem to have hit a wall, this is what I have so far:

```
from Tkinter import *


class TrafficLights(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Traffic Lights")
        self.grid()
        x='white'
        y='white'
        z='green'

        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width = 300, height = 400, bg = "black")
        self.canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(100, 50, 200, 350)

        self.canvas.create_oval(100, 50, 200, 150, fill=x)
        self.canvas.create_oval(100, 150, 200, 250, fill=y)
        self.canvas.create_oval(100, 250, 200, 350, fill=z)
def main():
    TrafficLights().mainloop()

main()
```

I have no clue what to do from here, I've searched through a few Tkinter tutorials and can't seem to find anything that could point me in the right direction.

Sorry I should have made that more clear, I want it to start at green then switch to amber, then red, then back to green with 2 second intervals between each.

Comment: The [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) method may be useful to you.

Comment: similarly consider using the `time` module, putting your ovals in a list and cycling through that list at 2 second intervals with time.

Comment: @Scironic That doesn't work with Tkinter directly, since it needs everything done in its own event loop. Kevin's comment is already right. If you don't want to use `after` you have to use nasty threads and this stuff.

Comment: @Scironic that's less effective for a couple of reasons - time is not guaranteed to return (though it usually does) and it's a busy wait which means you can't do anything (including close) your application until after time has finished.

Comment: @TidB, you're right, I'm suggesting it more as an alternative that is also useable outside of `tkinter`

Comment: @TidB threads and Tkinter's mainloop do *not* play nice - at least they didn't the last time I made the mistake of trying that. `after` is arguably not just the best but the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into the [`after...`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm) commands. A simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk
# py2
#import Tkinter as tk

class Fun(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("I say things")

        self.count = 0
        self.count_str = tk.StringVar()
        self.count_str.set(str(self.count))

        tk.Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.count_str).pack()

    def more_count(self):
        self.after(2000, self.more_count)
        self.count += 1
        self.count_str.set(str(self.count))


f = Fun()
f.more_count()
f.mainloop()
```

Comment: I seem to still be doing something wrong, am I supposed to redefine the x, y and z when using the self.after? Also 2000 in ms is just 2 seconds right?

Comment: @Mithellin you'll have to know what color you're currently showing and what color to show next. You might just write three functions: `show_red` `show_amber` and `show_green`. Then in each function you can call `after` with the *next* color.

Comment: I'm not sure if painting new shapes on the canvas requires more memory, though.